# is it possible to get back to my application after clicking google maps?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, application-state

We have made an application for a city in the netherlands that wants tourists to visit their lovely museums.

when they reach the page fo a museum we have a little icon that they press and they get transported to google maps which shows them where they are and how to get to the museum.

What we would need is a back button so we can get back to the previous page inside the cities application. Now it opens google maps and immediately closes the application. So when I am done with their maps part I have to close google maps and reopen my application and find the right page again. Quite a nuisance

Is it possible to embed this page or maybe even use something else then google maps?

Answer (score 6):

iPhone SDK 3.0 offers in-application Maps access. So use the [Map Kit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/maps.html) instead of linking to the Google Maps application.

This is used in Dutch applications like 9292OV, iNap, etc.